# Abel's test for series convergence

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Abel's test says that if $a_n$ converges and $b_n$ is monotone and bounded then, 
$\sum {{a_n}{b_n}} $ converges.

We demand that $b_n$ is monotone and bounded, isn't it like demanding $b_n$ has a finite limit, as $a_n$ does?

Comment: Do you want to say $\sum a_n$ is convergent?

Comment: It's not enough for $a_n$ to just converge. For example, take $a_n=b_n=\frac{1}{\sqrt n}.$

Comment: This isn't correct. Let $a_n=1=b_n$ for all $n\in \mathbb N$.

Comment: As already noted, you need to assume that $\sum a_n$ converges, not just that $a_n$ converges. Secondly, it *does* follow that $b_n$ has a finite limit, but this in itself is not enough to show convergence of $\sum a_nb_n$. Monotonicity of $b_n$ is important.

Comment: If I remember correctly, the proof is done examining $\sum s_k (b_k-b_{k-1})$ where $s_k=\sum_{n=0}^k a_n$ are the partial sums.

Comment: OK. Thanks everybody!

Comment: There's another version of Abel's test, where you require only that the partial sums of $\sum a_n$ are bounded, but in turn you must assume that $b_n$ is monotone and tends to $0$. This is particularly well-suited for series like $\sum\frac{\cos n}{n^\alpha}$, where $\alpha>0$.

Comment: @Etienne That one is usually called Dirichlet's test (but I know that the terminology is a little shaky).

Comment: Ah, OK. I never called it Dirichlet's test. French terminology... Thanks for letting me know that.